# What kind of VS 2010 C++ Project I must choose to compile a simple Borland C++ 5 Console app?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++builder

I have a simple Win32 console (no vcl) app written in Borland C++ 5, now I want compile the same application in VS 2010. but I'm new using this IDE and I don't know how run the code in VS. I tried choosing  Win32 Console Application. but even i very simple app like this

```
#include <iostream.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

does not compile in VS.

So, What kind of VS 2010 C++ Project I must choose to compile a simple Borland C++ 5 Console app? or I need modify my app in order to use VS C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<iostream.h>` is deprecated, and VS10 does not support it, use `<iostream>` instead, and you'll also need `std::cout`, `std::endl` , etc.. i.e.

```
#include <iostream>    
#pragma hdrstop

// #pragma argsused // I don't believe this is valid in VS10

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to prefix your library uses with `std::`, you can put a using declaration at the top, after the headers:

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Neither of the `#pragma`s used are valid in VC++, so those need to go.

Comment: Yes and for legacy code, you can put a single using namespace std; at the top. Not the best practice for new code, but in your case it makes sense.

Comment: @ildjarn: hdrstop apparently is.

Comment: The code doesn't compile if I don't add the `#include "stdafx.h"` to the source, is this mandatory?

Comment: @Salvador: It is if you compile it to use a precompiled header, and the name of your precompiled header is "stdafx.h".  Both of these options are the default case when you create a new project.